# charset of the attribute values in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, ascii, kotlin

I use the Jsoup and I need to pick up attribute values of all tags inside an html document in ascii-encoding maintaining them as they are, without converting them.

So, I have the following html document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ascii">        
</head>
<body>
    <div title="2 &gt; 1, 1 > 0, &agrave; vs &egrave;">
        3 &gt; 2,  1 > 0
    </div>
</body>
```

which I want to parse by means of Jsoup.

I need to extract the value of `title` attribite exactly as it is: `2 &gt; 1, 1 > 0, &agrave; vs &egrave;`.

I've create a `Document` object `doc` as below (it is in Kotlin, but I don't think it important here):

```
val charset = Charset.forName("ascii")
val doc = Jsoup.parse(File("test.html").readText(charset))
doc.outputSettings().charset(charset)
```

When I print out the doc by means of

```
println(doc.toString())
```

I get the following string

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="ascii"> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div title="2 > 1, 1 > 0, &agrave; vs &egrave;">
    3 &gt; 2 
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

which differs from the file content by the `title` attribute value (`&gt;` gets transformed into `>` in string `"2 > 1"`), while the rest of the document is OK.

Then, inspecting the attribute value

```
 doc.body().select("div").forEach { div -> println("title = ${div.attr("title")}") }
```

produces the following string

```
title = 2 > 1, 1 > 0, à vs è
```

Notice, that `&agrave;` and `&egrave;` get transformed into `à` and `è`.

My question is: in Jsoup, how can I get attribute values of the html tags preserving the way they are written in the input file?

In the example above I need to get the string `"2 &gt; 1, 1 > 0, &agrave; vs &egrave;"` (as it is written in the input file) and not `"2 > 1, 1 > 0, &agrave; vs &egrave;"` niether `"2 &gt; 1, 1 &gt; 0, à vs è"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `attr()` method returns a String without the HTML entities and I could not find a way to keep the HTML entities. However, you can use the `Jsoup.clean()` method to convert the characters in the string to entities.

```
val charset = Charset.forName("ascii")
val doc = Jsoup.parse(File("test.html").readText(charset))
doc.body().select("div").forEach { div ->
    val title = Jsoup.clean("${div.attr("title")}", "", Whitelist.none(), Document.OutputSettings().charset(charset))
    println("title = $title")
}
```

The result is:

```
title = 2 &gt; 1, &agrave; vs &egrave;
```

Of course, this might not be a good solution for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but in this case all symbols are transformed into html entitites. I mean that if the html file contains `<div title="2 &gt; 1, 1 > 0">`, the script above transforms it into `<div title="2 &gt; 1, 1 &gt; 0">`, while I'd like to have them exactly as they are in the file. 
P.S. I've updated the question adding more specifications.

Comment: I did some more experiments, but it seems that jsoup always convert the `&gt;` entities to `>` for attributes; and the `>` characters for entities to `&gt;` in normal HTML. Do you specifically need any features from jsoup? If not, you might be better off using a standard XML parser.

Comment: Not that I am constrained to use Jsoup, but I would not like to discard it for the encoding-related issue. I think there should be a way out.